# React-native firebase Google Sign in Android

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm having trouble returning a refresh token from Firebase Google Sign in React native:

On iOS there is no issue returning the refresh token but on Android I am having trouble.

here is the code:

```
// Get the users ID token
  const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

  // Create a Google credential with the token
  const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

  const user_sign_In = await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential)
```

on iOS the user_sign_in response is:

```
 {
        uid: 'CORRECT_USER ID',
        email: 'CORRECT_EMAIL',
        refreshToken: 'WORKING_REFRESH_TOKEN',
        displayName: 'CORRECT NAME',
}
```

from the same code I get back on Android:

```
 {
        uid: 'CORRECT_USER ID',
        email: 'CORRECT_EMAIL',
        displayName: 'CORRECT NAME',
}
```

I want to know how I can get the Refresh token back on Android.

```
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "7.2.2"
```

Comment: Did you configure the `webClientId`?

Comment: hi @DánielBoros yes I believe I have correctly configured the Web Client ID as the sign in method works on both ios and android but for some reason it doesn't return a refresh token on Android. Any help is welcome!